# SWIFT 3 - No '*' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSNumber'

Tags: swift, xcode8

I have issue on Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

[image]

I have error here. 
statusPrefix = formatter.string(from: (numParticles.rawValue * 4) )! + " Particles"

Comment: Think about it: What type has `rawValues * 4`? What argument type is expected by `string(from: ...)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `from` expects a value of type `NSNumber`. You'll have to convert the result of the multiplication into one:

```
var number = NSNumber(value: numParticles.rawValue * 4)
statusPrefix = NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: number, number: NumberFormatter.Style.decimal)
```

Comment: Sure, what do you want to explain?

Comment: What did you do differently than the OP, and why it works. Simple errors are often caused by beginners in the technology, who potentially would not understand what you changed to fix it. Remember that SO questions are much more helpful to the thousands of viewers that have the same problem and found it via search than the actual asker.

Comment: The error happened because "from:" expects a NSNumber.

Comment: ... and to do so, you had to convert the result of the multiplication into one, and pass that into the `localizedString`. I'll add edit that into the answer.

Comment: You could also write without creating a new variable: `statusPrefix = NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: NSNumber(value: numParticles.rawValue * 4), number: NumberFormatter.Style.decimal)`